# Sublime text- defining relative paths in settings?

Tags: relative-path, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm trying to create, on Windows, a fully portable environment that contains git, python with all the packages I want, and, of course, Sublime. Since it's going to be portable, I'd like to be able to point SublimeGit at a relative path to the git directory. I understand that relative paths should start from the Data folder, however `..\\bin\\git.exe` fails with a message that Sublime cannot find git. How should I define a relative path in a settings file, then?

Comment: have you tried starting from the `Packages` folder? `..\\..\\bin\\git.exe`

Comment: This sounds like a question for the SublimeGit plugin. Some plugins are not designed to work with relative paths, you should ask the author of the plugin to clarify (unless they explicitly state it is supported somewhere).

Comment: @MattDMo: Yes, I have, actually, but forgot to mention it. It didn't work, either. To skuroda: I'll ask, but as far as I can tell, SublimeGit is just looking for git in the directory specified/the path.

Comment: I know, but you can request that all relative directories are based on some known location (such as the packages directory). I just wrote a quick test plugin for my non portable version of ST, and the cwd (from  the plugins perspective) is the location of the executable. Unless it's explicitly stated in the plugin, it may not be trying to resolve from the same location you expect it to. I've never looked at the plugin, so I can't say for sure.